# Syntax Highlighting in VS Code for Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, syntax-highlighting

I am staring at my Lightning component in VS Code and I am a little weary by the sea of green strings in attributes which often contain some non-trivial functions.

I have installed the VS Code Salesforce Extensions and mostly are working well though there is no specific highlighting for the string attributes when working with expression syntax such as `{! 'slds-combobox_container' + if(not(empty(v.selected)), ' slds-has-selection', '')}`.

Is there already a way to add syntax highlighting to these strings that I am missing? Is it even possible to customise a TM scope to address this? TM scopes and themes are completely foreign to me but would be willing to invest the effort if it is indeed possible. Any thoughts would be most appreciated.

[image: syntax highlighting in vscode for lightning components]

Thanks

Comment: You may install the extension Salesforce Extensions for VS Code -> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode. It includes a number of extensions for VF/Apex/Lightning.

Comment: I should of mentioned that I do indeed have the Salesforce Extensions installed. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write your own extension, this is well documented for VSCode e.g. [Language Extension Guidelines](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/language-support). And the source code of the Salesforce extensions are available at [Salesforce Extensions for VS Code](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode) and that includes [developing.md](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/blob/develop/docs/developing.md). A starting point would be [salesforcedx-vscode-lightning](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/tree/develop/packages/salesforcedx-vscode-lightning).

However there would be these challenges:

- There may be no published grammar for those strings
- Big learning curve unless you are already expert in [TextMate Grammar](https://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars)/NodeJs/JavaScript/VSCode
- Salesforce might have this in their plans for the future (so best to try to check before investing your own time only to have that work superceeded)

Comment: Thanks Keith, I'll look into this. The best outcome is that Salesforce might have a roadmap for this.